# What seems to be plaguing my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently had to toss an old desktop of mine. It was gradually getting slower, and after shutting the desktop down for long periods of time, it would choke up on startup. Sometimes it'd give a disk read error, sometimes say no OS was found, etc. Restarting it  5-15, it times would eventually boot properly. I also noticed that startup programs were going missing, Dropbox was reindexing my entire folder, and Backblaze was backing up less than the number of files that it should. This lead me to believe it was probably a hard drive issue. I began to wonder why I'd have hard drive issues, and came to closure when I assumed it was because of recent power surges and outages. I'm sure that does a number on the drive.

I bought a new desktop recently, and I bought an uninterruptable power supply on top of that to protect it outages that might scramble the drive.

I set this up a few days ago and two days ago, I noticed Dropbox was reindexing my entire Dropbox folder. I installed both Dropbox and Backblaze on this system, but it is very much more lightweight than the other. Only about 15 third-party applications installed. I thought that maybe Dropbox and Backblaze were stressing my system, so I turned off Backblaze. Still, Dropbox runs and comes across this infinite reindex issue. I noticed that upon a reboot recently, two applications did not start on startup either. Also, much like my old desktop, every 3rd or 4th reboot, I'll be forced into a chkdsk. What could be going wrong with my years-old desktop that is now immediately causing the same issues to my new one?

I've considered all of the basics. I'm in a very air conditioned room. I run routine virus scans. I'd like to think I take care of my systems very well. What is this issue that is haunting me? There's always the possibility that this new desktop has a junk hard drive, but it just seems way too coincidental.

Comment: Very long question dude, would like to help but ain't got the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is a coincidence but mind telling us what applications you have installed? Check disk usually runs when the computer is turned off incorrectly and Windows wants to run a scan to see if there are any errors on the drive (Check disk is useless btw, if you wanted to seriously test your drive use [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm)).